# Strange modules style behaviour when loading similar module position twice

Tags: module, module-display

I want to load a module position twice with different module style, but strangely the style on the 2nd position load is always following the 1st one.

The code is like this :

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-7" style="raw"/>
<div> ....
....
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-7" style="xhtml"/>
```

So, the second position-7 always loads the modules using 'raw' style not xhtml. Is it a joomla bug or it's indeed designed like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you trying to define the same position twice? I doubt Joomla supports multiple positions with the same name. How is that supposed to work?

You should instead give the second position a different name. Then this one can have another default style.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  I was actually trying to create a responsive mega menu where all same menu items and modules automatically converted/displayed in the offcanvas area when user visiting the website from mobile devices, so in this case I need to call the modules twice.

Comment: That doesn't sound like something which is supported by Joomla.
Make two positions and duplicate the modules. They can point to the same menu.